# jstring base64 to string conversion

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am working on cocos2dx project, in a JNI call, method returns a java string which contains base64 encoded string, but as soon I try to get that from jstring to const char in C++ side it gives error, can you help me out here ?

```
  string getBase64EncodingJNI(std::string pData) {
  JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
            if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "com/abc/something/modules/myHelper", "getBase64Encoding", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;")) {

            jstring jData;
            if (!pData.c_str())
                jData = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF("");
            else
                jData = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(pData.c_str());

            jstring output =  (jstring) methodInfo.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID,jData);
            const char *strReturn = methodInfo.env->GetStringUTFChars(output, 0);
            string outputData = strReturn;

            methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
            methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(jData);
            methodInfo.env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(output, strReturn);
            return outputData;
    }
return "";
```

}

this is the methods being called

```
public static String getBase64Encoding(String pdata) {
    String encodedStr = Base64.encodeToString (pdata.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedStr;
}
```

I get error on line `GetStringUTFChars` I want to ready that encoded jstring and pass it to other function. Error is 
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetStringUTFChars called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Comment: what error? what you get?

Comment: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetStringUTFChars called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Comment: @Zubair Please add such information to your question instead o a comment.

Comment: @ user0042 edited my question.

Comment: your `jData` is most likely not a base-64 string, see http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/Base64.java#160

Comment: @pskink jData is simple string which will be encoded to base64 and returned back, the problem occurs when I try to get the result from output (returned by that function) which is base64 encoded version. GetStringUTFChars works fine if I get simple jstring. it gives error when returned jstring is base64 encoded.

Comment: post your full code - with setting `methodInfo` fields

Comment: @pskink edited and posted full code

Comment: are you sure you are not calling `decode` method? as you can see `throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad base-64");` is called only [here](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/Base64.java#160)

Comment: @pskink as you can see in line JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo, method name specified is getBase64Encoding, so yeah am sure.

Comment: so why are you getting `IllegalArgumentException` with `"bad base-64"` error message then? again, it is called only from `decode()` method

Comment: @pskink that was the problem, wrong function called from earlier class hierarchy. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `if (!pData.c_str())` will NEVER evaluate as false, because `c_str()` never returns a NULL pointer. If you want to check the pointer, use `if (!pData.data())` instead. Better would be `if (pData.empty())`.  Or, just remove the `if` altogether, since `NewStringUTF("")` and `NewStringUTF(pData.c_str())` are the same thing when the string is empty, so just call `NewStringUTF(pData.c_str())` unconditionally

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for you comment, but my issue is solved.